# White screen when I try to add qml app with MapboxGl in yocto build

Tags: qml, yocto, mapbox-gl

I want to create an image for raspberrypi4-64 with yocto and I tried to add a qml app that contains a map from MapboxGl, but when I run the app on raspberry the screen is white.

In my local.conf I added:

```
    PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase += " eglfs"
    PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtlocation += " geoservices_mapbox geoservices_mapboxgl geoclue"
    PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase += "sql-mysql sql-sqlite2 sql-sqlite gl gles2 "
    
    
    PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase += " accessibility gles2"
    PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtquickcontrols += " accessibility"
    DISTRO_FEATURES_remove += "x11 wayland"
    DISTRO_FEATURES_append += "opengl gles2"
```

Any help please?

I also connected the raspberry to wi-fi.